# Is there a way automatically to collect analytics data from goo.gl into Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, goo.gl

Specifically I am looking to automatically bring the total clicks from my links into a spreadsheet at specified time intervals.

Comment: So I found this API: https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#url_analytics

That seems to be on the right path. Now, is there a way to embed that into Excel and create a macro of some kind to either go collect that data at specified time intervals or to update every time you open the spreadsheet?